# Python inverted number pyramid exercise

Tags: python

This is an example of a correct pyramid.

[image: this is how my pyramid has to look like.]

I have this exercise as homework but I cant figure it out.

The code i've tried so far is this one and I can't make it inverted:

```py
n = 5
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
       for j in range(n, i-1, -1):
           print(j, end=" ") 
    
       print(" ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
n = int(input("What's the number: "))

for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    for j in range(i, 0, -1):
        print(j, end="")
    print()
```

Works for me.

The trick is to start the second loop "j" with the decrementing "i" downwards.

Imagine you are doing not a pyramid, but printing

`5 4 3 2 1` n times.

Something like

```
5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
...
```

You would start i and j at the same index, n, and just repeat the task.

Here, you start j at i, so each time i gets decremented, j starts from the decremented i, thus making a pyramid effect.

Hope you understand :)

Comment: Glad it helped! Please mark my answer as valid if you don't have further questions :)